# How to convert cartesian coordinates to complex numbers in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I have an array of Cartesian coordinates

```
xy = np.array([[0,0], [2,3], [3,4], [2,5], [5,2]])
```

which I want to convert into an array of complex numbers representing the same:

```
c = np.array([0, 2+3j, 3+4j, 2+5j, 5+2j])
```

My current solution is this:

```
c = np.sum(xy * [1,1j], axis=1)
```

This works but seems crude to me, and probably there is a nicer version with some built-in magic using `np.complex()` or similar, but the only way  I found to use this was

```
c = np.array(list(map(lambda c: np.complex(*c), xy)))
```

This doesn't look like an improvement.

Can anybody point me to a better solution, maybe using one of the many `numpy` functions I don't know by heart (is there a `numpy.cartesian_to_complex()` working on arrays I haven't found yet?), or maybe using some implicit conversion when applying a clever combination of operators?

Comment: What's the standard of "nice" and "crude" in this context? Also in the 2nd solution the call to `list()` isn't necessary.

Comment: @CongMa why do you say it's not necessary? If I leave it out then my array is a single map object turnign the dtype of the array to `object`... not very useful.

Comment: @CongMa The `list` is necessary in Python3 (and harmless in Python2).  Well, converting something using summing and multiplying where in theory only a reinterpretation should be necessary, doesn't seem "nice" even though it works.

Comment: I see; perhaps we could add the `python-3.x` tag. This is indeed a big difference between the two Pythons. Also if the code runs with Python 3, we could replace `np.array` with `np.fromiter()` and eliminate a `list()` call.

Comment: @CongMa that's a good suggestion... although in this little `xy` example doesn't produce a change in performance.

Comment: `np.fromiter()` would indeed have been an improvement (will try to memorize it for the next time).  But using `list()` or not or using `fromiter()` instead is not the topic of the question at all (so is whether some example aims as Python3, so please don't add a Python3 tag), so changing that would not solve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recognize that `complex128` is just a pair of floats.  You can then do this using a "view" which is free, after converting the dtype from int to float (which I'm guessing your real code might already do):

```
xy.astype(float).view(np.complex128)
```

The `astype()` converts the integers to floats, which requires construction of a new array, but once that's done the `view()` is "free" in terms of runtime.

The above gives you `shape=(n,1)`; you can `np.squeeze()` it to remove the extra dimension.  This is also just a view operation, so takes basically no time.

Comment: My quick test didn't show that doing the `np.squeeze` is "for free", but it might be an artifact of the small `xy` sample.

Comment: Yes, in my usecase the input comes as floats :)  I compared your solution to J...S's and found it to be 1000 times faster with an input of 100k coordinates. (`xy[:,0]+1j*xy[:,1]` vs. `xy.view(np.complex).squeeze()`).

Comment: In fact, the size of the input doesn't seem to be relevant, the solution has a constant effort (O(1)).  Perfect :)

Comment: @Alfe: Yes, if your input data is already `float` as I suspected, then this solution runs in constant time.  Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
c=xy[:,0]+1j*xy[:,1]
```

`xy[:,0]` will give an array of all elements in the `0`th column of `xy` and `xy[:,1]` will give that of the `1`st column.

Multiply `xy[:,1]` with `1j` to make it imaginary and then add the result with `xy[:,0]`.

Comment: Yes.  This is about 3x faster on my machine, and easier to understand.

Comment: Though this is beautiful and KISS (⁺¹ for this), it still is about factor 1000 slower than John Zwinck's approach which also comes closer to my idea of just reinterpreting what's already in memory.

Comment: Actually, this has O(n) while JZ's solution has O(1).  But still far nicer than my approach ;-)

Comment: If performance isn't an issue, I'd simply go with `xy @ [1, 1j]`

Comment: @MarkDickinson Wow!  I've just learned about the `@` as operator.  And have problems finding documentation about it.  Can you provide a pointer?

Comment: @Alfe: It is simply the dot product.  `np.dot(xy, [1,1j])` is the same thing.

Comment: I found out by now that `a @ b` calls `a.__matmul__(b)`.  Never heard of that before.  And sure, that will call the `np.dot()` then.